# How to make POST Request through react.js?

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch

I am trying to make POST request call through react,but i am getting error.If any body knows help me out and please assist me where i have to changes.

Error is: {timestamp: 1510396949738, status: 415, error: "Unsupported Media exception: "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException", message: "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----Web…daryTY6125I1exH8Ry7f;charset=UTF-8' not supported", … …}

Here my React code:

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
const style = {
  margin: 15,
marginLeft: 600
};
export default class  Register extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;


    var data = new FormData();
    const payload = {
    id: self.refs.id.getValue(),
    studentName: self.refs.sname.getValue(),
    age: self.refs.age.getValue(),
    emailId: self.refs.emailId.getValue()
};
data.append("myjsonkey", JSON.stringify(payload));

fetch('http://localhost:8083/students/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
    body: data
  })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
      }).then(function(body) {
        console.log(body);
      });
  }

render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <div style={style}>
      <TextField ref='id'
      hintText="Enter Student id"
      floatingLabelText="id"
      />
      <br/>
      <TextField ref='sname'
      hintText="Enter your Last Name"
      floatingLabelText="StudentName"
      />
      <br/>
      <TextField ref='age'
      hintText="Enter your Age"
      floatingLabelText="age"
      />
      <br/>

      <TextField ref='emailId'
      hintText="Enter your Email"
      floatingLabelText="emailId"
      />
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" />


      </div>
          </form>


    );
  }


}
```

Comment: As the error message says: _UserAlreadyExistException_. Isn't this the problem?

Comment: @mersocarlin No it's not that problem, but default it showing that message.

Comment: why are you using refs? it is depricated, instead you should [pass a function for the ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element)

Comment: For getting value of  `sname...`, etc. shouldn't you be using `self.refs.sname.value` ?

Comment: @aquaman i am new to reactjs, i thought we can use self.refs.sname.getValue(). If it is wrong please suggest me correct way.Thank you

Comment: @SpRaju I am new to reactjs too but things work out fine for me if I use `.value.trim()`. However I think `.trim()` is not necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `body` is missing from [fetch#post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) request.

`body` should be instance of `FormData` in your case.Or could be instance of other type like `ArrayBuffer`,`Blob/File` .. etc.

```
var data = new FormData();
const payload = {
    id: self.refs.id,
    studentName: self.refs.sname,
    age: self.refs.age,
    emailId: self.refs.emailId

};
data.append("myjsonkey", JSON.stringify(payload));

fetch('http://localhost:8083/students/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
})
```

For more you [`Fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: @RIYAZ KHAN now i am getting "status: 415, error: "Unsupported Media Type", could u please look once